# How can i get alternate images of array with different height using flexbox

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I have array of object ImageKist where I would like to show alternate image with different heights using flexbox as shown below:[image]

where images go from left to right. How can I achieve above pattern using flexbox.

Install styled-component: npm install --save styled-components

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-curie-jesyz1?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: can you provide a sandbox ?

Comment: you gonne define two image styles 1 for 1st picture and 2nd for 2nd picture and while mapping on images you gonna check if the index is even then use 1st style and if it's even use 2nd style

Comment: @Johan: Please find sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-curie-jesyz1?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2** (for `glitz`)

It seems that the library mentioned in comments uses a syntax similar to `styled-components`, I have made some changes to the code and it seems to work for me.

Forked demo with modifications: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/glitz-react-0d7njl?file=/src/App.tsx)

Example:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { styled } from "@glitz/react";

const imageList = [] as any;
for (let i = 1; i < 52; i++) {
  imageList.push({
    id: `${i}`,
    url: `https://picsum.photos/500?random=${i}`
  });
}

const Wrapper = styled.div({
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
  gridAutoRows: "80px",
  gap: "30px",
  gridAutoFlow: "row dense"
});

const ImageWrapper = styled.div({
  overflow: "hidden",
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: "20px",
  gridRow: "span 2",
  gridColumn: "auto",
  ":nth-of-type(even)": {
    gridRow: "span 3"
  },
  ":nth-of-type(6n+5)": {
    gridColumn: "2"
  }
});

const ImageStyled = styled.img({
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  objectFit: "cover"
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {imageList.map((image: any) => (
        <ImageWrapper key={image.id}>
          <ImageStyled src={image.url} alt={image.url} />
          <h4 style={{ position: "absolute", top: "16px", color: "white" }}>
            {image.id}
          </h4>
        </ImageWrapper>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

**Update 1** (for `styled-components`)

I updated the answer to omit the use of `index` as a prop to create the layout, instead uses `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class to alter the styles, so this is now kind of a all CSS solution.

It still uses `grid` layout, but hopefully it could help.

Live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hr19gn?file=src/App.js)

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Test data
const imageList = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 52; i++) {
  imageList.push({
    id: `${i}`,
    url: `https://picsum.photos/500?random=${i}`,
  });
}

// Styled components
const Wrapper = styled.div`
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 80px;
gap: 30px;
grid-auto-flow: row dense;
& > div {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: auto;
}
& > div:nth-of-type(even) {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
& > div:nth-of-type(6n+5) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
`;

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border-radius: 20px;
`;

const ImageStyled = styled.img`
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
`;

const H4Styled = styled.h4`
position: absolute;
top: 16px;
color: white;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        {imageList.map((image, index) => (
          <ImageWrapper key={image.id} index={index}>
            <ImageStyled src={image.url} alt={image.url} />
            <H4Styled>{image.id}</H4Styled>
          </ImageWrapper>
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please check this sandbox link where styling library I am using is glitz and not styled component. Can you please look into it https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-curie-jesyz1?file=/src/App.tsx ? In glitz I can not use 'grid-row: span 2' same as styled components

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar My bad, this question still mentioned `styled-component` and has the tag, so I assumed that  `styled-component`  was used.

Comment: sorry. I will make the necessary changes

Comment: I have updated the question now. please find the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-curie-jesyz1?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar Thanks for the update, I made some changes to the code and it seems to work for me, and I updated the forked demo to the answer. This seems to be using a similar syntax to `styled-component`, although I have not used this library before so perhaps also reference their [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@glitz/react#getting-started) in the actual project.

Comment: Thank you. It worked now. gridRowStart worked instead gridRow in my code

Comment: Can you help me to solve the problem with this https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ives-ewfljj?file=/src/App.tsx ? here I have used 'gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(4, 1fr)", instead of 'gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",' some slides are not working. Can you please look into it?

Comment: John Li: can you please look into above comment?

Comment: Hi @MeAtWork I just noticed the comment, let me have a look in the new question post to avoid lengthy discussion in the comments here.

Comment: John Li: Please find the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630423/getting-problem-in-flowing-images-from-left-to-right-i-e-1-2-3-4-more-u