# Getting problem in flowing images from left to right (i.e. 1,2,3,4...... more) using grid

Tags: reactjs, grid, css-in-js

Getting problem in flowing images from left to right using grid. Some images are not flowing from left to right as per number as shown in image (like 5th image should come before image 6. Same with image 9). Images should be shown from left to right with numbers [image]

Here is my code sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ives-ewfljj?file=/src/App.tsx

Note: This code works fine when gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)", but gives problem with gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(4, 1fr)"

Please help me to solve the problem and achieve the following format:
[image]

Mobile view looks little different that desktop view where card 4 comes to place of card 3 and further like card 8 comes place of card 7 as shown below image: [image]

How to check mobile view on code sandbox:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

I tried to create an experimental example that responsively switch from 4 to 2 column grid, which hopefully matches the desired layout.

Demo of the example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/glitz-list-res-3v2zrt?file=/src/App.tsx)

Although initially preferred a cleaner solution over a chunk of `nth-of-type` conditions, I switched back to the `nth-of-type` approach anyways in the above updated example in order to implement the responsive conditions.

Also had to manually add some specificity to make the `styled` work correctly. Since my experience with the `glitz` library is limited, I suspect that there would be more flexible solution, such as interpolating with props like we do in `styled-components`.

**Update 1**

If the goal is to transform the 3 columns layout to 4 columns, I think styling conditionally in the iteration might be more flexible than with the `nth-of-type` conditions, and it also add support for more complex conditions.

This following example uses conditional styles in the component to create the desired layout. The `glitz` library used in the project seems to support dynamic styles with a `css` prop on the component, which probably could also be used to replace the `style` prop here.

Forked demo with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/glitz-list-4-col-ntkyqf?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
interface imageItem {
  id: string;
  url: string;
}
```

```
const ImageWrapper = styled.div({
  overflow: "hidden",
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: "20px",
  gridRowStart: "span 2",
  gridColumnStart: "auto"
});
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {imageList.map((image, index) => {
        return (
          <ImageWrapper
            key={image.id}
            style={{
              gridRow: [2, 4, 5, 7].includes((index + 1) % 8)
                ? "span 3"
                : "span 2",
              gridColumn: (index + 1) % 8 === 6 ? "2" : "auto"
            }}
          >
            <ImageStyled src={image.url} alt={image.url} />
            <h4 style={{ position: "absolute", top: "16px", color: "red" }}>
              {image.id}
            </h4>
          </ImageWrapper>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: John Solution is not working on my local setup. Can I get a solution using styling like nth-of-type like   ":nth-of-type(even)": {
    gridRow: "span 3"
  },
  ":nth-of-type(6n+5)": {
    gridColumn: "2"
  }

Comment: @MeAtWork For 4 columns layout I think the conditional logic might not work with `nth-of-type` at least in a clean way. Could it be the `css` prop from the `glitz` library not working? I've updated the answer with a standard `style` prop for a similar result.

Comment: Let me check once again. I will get back to you.

Comment: John Li: Desktop view works fine but Mobile view looks little different than desktop view where card 4 comes to place of card 3 and further like card 8 comes place of card 7 as shown above image. Please help me to solve this problem where format is 1,2,4,3,5,6,8,7...... in mobile view only. You can update code here https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-pond-j85c3n

Comment: @MeAtWork Is _mobile view_ a browser feature or an option with codesandbox? The new link seems to be running fine for me.

Comment: John, Yes. May be login in code sandbox. check rightmost corner you can see folder type icon. Sent you image above. It would be also helpful if site can be made responsive also from desktop to mobile view

Comment: @MeAtWork At least for me it does seems to keep the right order of images, even with this option on. Could it be a browser behavior? I used the latest Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: There seems to be development work going on. Try accessing that link again later. but I have used the same code provided by you above so you can try that also.

Comment: @MeAtWork Actually in the posted image I can see that the layout changes to 2 columns in your mobile version screenshot. Unlike the example we worked on, I think the actually project must be changing the columns responsively and that could have caused the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252301/discussion-between-meatwork-and-john-li).